# JavaScript Поиск в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
[{
  login: 'test1',
  pass: '123'
},
{
  login: 'test2',
  pass: '123456'
}]
```

Как проверить, есть ли пользователь с логином test2 в этом массиве??

Comment: [`array.find(user => user.login === 'test2') !== undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для поиска можно использовать метод [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Например:

```js
var arr = [{
    login: 'test1',
    pass: '123'
  },
  {
    login: 'test2',
    pass: '123456'
  }
];
console.log(arr.some(el => el.login == 'test2'))
```

Comment: А использовать методом some можно или includes в чем-то выигрывает?

Comment: @Grundy Приведенный код для массива из вопроса возвращает `false`, а автору надо `true`. Возникает вопрос: кто ты такой, и что ты сделал с настоящим @Grundy? :)

Comment: @Yaant, поправил, почему-то показалось, что includes тоже callback принимает.

Comment: @diraria, Да, перепутал с методом `some`.

Comment: @Lukas, методом some - нужно :-) includes принимает сам элемент, а some - callback, который принимает элемент и возвращает true или false

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо ;) А то думал может тут какое-то кунг фу, которое я еще не постиг :)